# Prevent adding an object to an array that already exists

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a input field that calls the `fetchGames` function:

```
fetchGames: debounce(function (searchQuery) {
  this.gallery.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.Key.includes(searchQuery)) {
      this.filteredGallery.push(item.Key)
    } else {
      this.filteredGallery.splice(index, 1)
    }
  })
}, 500)
```

This sort of works. My `gallery` array his 3 objects:

```
gallery: ['bali', 'brass', 'eclipse']
```

When I type `a` it adds `bali` and `brass` to the `filterGallery` array.

When I add the `l` (to make `al`) to the input the function removes `brass` from the array as expected but it adds another `bali` to the array because the `item.Key` does also include `al`.

How do I prevent adding an object to an array that already exists in the array?

ps. Using Vue2 in which you cannot use `v-for` on a Set object (afaik).

Comment: Try using a `Set` instead of an `Array`, that way you can just call `set.add` and not worry about duplicates

Comment: Yeah,  just use `Set` or add another `if` statement that checks if that string is already in filteredGallery. Personally I'd shorten it and use filter with includes like `this.filteredGallery = this.gallery.map((item) => item.Key).filter((item) => item.includes(searchQuery))`

Comment: Maybe I should've said I'm using Vue2 to loop through the `filteredGallery` and it doesn't look like you can v-for through a Set object. Thanks @DominikMatis that did the trick. Smart to map and the filter that result and return it to the array variable. IF you want to put that in an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: i would just create a class for this gallery which controls it

Comment: @PeterBoomsma ... are there any questions left regarding the array mutating approach that was recently provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can erase your arr in every input change, or add another if statement which will check filteredGallery and don't push items which it allready include

Comment: Yea thought about that, but then I would have a loop in a loop which is not great. Clearing the array is an option.

Answer (score 0):

As per other comments, a Set would do the trick. You can use the following pattern to ensure the resulting array won't include duplicates.

`[...new Set([...currentValues, newValue])]`

Notice how the Set is spread into an array so you should be good to go using `v-for`.

Comment: It seems like Set doesn't work with Vue2. Cannot use v-for with a Set object.

Comment: You spread the Set into an Array so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided by the OP, and taking into account the limitations, an approach was to always mutate the `filteredGallery`. With every search one first does empty/reset the array by setting its `length` to zero. Then one does reduce the `gallery` array by providing the just emptied `filteredGallery` as the callbacks collecting array, where one does push into all the matching items of the new search ...

```
fetchGames: debounce(function (searchQuery) {
  this.filteredGallery.length = 0; // reset.

  this.gallery.reduce((arr, { Key }) => {
    if (Key.includes(searchQuery)) {

      arr.push(Key); // push into collector.
    }
    return arr;

  }, this.filteredGallery); // collector.

}, 500)
```

The above provided code got slightly changed into an executable snippet in order to prove the suggested approach ...

```js
function fetchGamesAtBoundComponent(searchQuery) {
  this.filteredGallery.length = 0; // reset.

  this.gallery.reduce((arr, { Key }) => {
    if (Key.includes(searchQuery)) {

      arr.push(Key); // push into collector.
    }
    return arr;

  }, this.filteredGallery); // collector.
}

const component = {
  gallery: [
    { Key: 'bali' },
    { Key: 'brass' },
    { Key: 'eclipse' },
  ],
  filteredGallery: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
};
const fetchGames =
  fetchGamesAtBoundComponent.bind(component);

console.log(
  "default state ...",
  { component }
);
fetchGames('a');

console.log(
  "fetchGames('a') ...",
  { component }
);
fetchGames('al');

console.log(
  "fetchGames('al') ...",
  { component }
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @PeterBoomsma ... are there any questions left regarding the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you map the array to include only Key attributes and then filter by those that includes specific substring

Example script here:

```js
this.filteredGallery = this.gallery.map((item) => item.Key).filter((item) => item.includes(searchQuery))
```